# Is it possible to remove Staedtler ink from a paper?

Tags: drafting

I am practicing engineering drafting and sometimes I am near on finishing my work but suddenly I make a mistake. Is it possible to remove the ink? If yes, how? Where can I buy such tools? I am using a [Staedtler's Mars Matic 0.5mm](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001U3RCGQ).

Comment: How does ink have anything to do with drafting, since drafting is done on a computer?

Comment: Oh, sorry. I really don't know. I'm a first year electrical engineering student.

Comment: @OlinLathrop, hand drawing is still called "drafting" in the building engineering world.  Just because computers have supplanted hand drafting doesn't mean the process has changed names.

Comment: @grfr: My point is that no real drafting gets done with ink anymore, so this question makes little sense, or at least has little relevance to real life.

Comment: @OlinLathrup, colleges still teach hand drafting before computer drafting.  It's a good way to learn about lineweights, perspective, and general arrangement of drawings.  To me, it's like learning Reimann sums before learning the shortcut method for integrals - you need to know the basis before you just blindly use the best method.  I still use hand-drawn sketches fairly frequently to convey ideas to my company's drafters and to clients.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To remove such ink it needs to scraped off, usually with a scalpel blade. This works well on thicker and more studier media such as film or vellum, but it will always be obvious where the erasure was made.

Depending on the amount of ink that needs to be removed and the robustness of the media, sometimes an ink erasure can work (such as a Staedtler blue ink eraser, [Mars Plastic Combo](http://www.staedtler.com/en/products/pencils-accessories/erasers/mars-plastic-combi-526-508-premium-quality-combi-eraser/)), but again it will be obvious where the erasure was made. This can work on paper, but only with thicker robust paper.

If you need to present a drawing of professional standard, redraw the entire drawing.

Comment: I am using a buff paper like [this](https://www.google.com.ph/url?sa=i&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=images&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjiitfHyrnKAhXo46YKHTuJBJIQjRwIBw&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com%2FEngineering-Computation-Letter-Sheets-35500%2Fdp%2FB001J87JTM&psig=AFQjCNH3mlKaBib3FsfSycFwMwRRfMU1ow&ust=1453420266609136) will the Mars Plastic Combo work?

Comment: You will most likely end up damaging the paper. Also, you will erase some of the already printed grid lines. You could do a test on another sheet of paper.

Answer (score 5):

> Is it possible to remove the ink?

A quick [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=erase%20mars%20matic&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#safe=off&q=mars%20matic%20erase%20ink) isn't turning up anything, as I more or less expected.  Ink isn't meant to be erased, so I'm going to hazard that there is no product that will erase the ink for this pen.

Normally, the only "erasable" ink pens I see are the cheap, consumer-grade pens that use a more standard-grade ink (erasable is a relative term - I've never seen an erasable pen where you can totally remove the ink from the paper).  Since the Staedtler pens are more professional-grade and use higher-quality inks, they are made to be indelible.

> sometimes I am near on finishing my work but suddenly I make a mistake.

The tongue-in-cheek response to this would be "stop making mistakes."  I know that's not really possible given that we're all human.  However, when it comes time to inking, you should really be focused on tracing lines that you already know are correct.  Inking is not the time to make changes.

Comment: +1 for tracing lines. Draft in pencil first - ink over the correct work, erase the pencil marks.

Answer (score 2):

I have used sand paper on drawings before, with varied results. Experiment with a mix of grits on a scrap piece, and see if it will work with your paper. If no sand paper, try nail files. If nothing, redraw.  Also Frixion makes magical erasable pens.

Comment: With a frixion, you can't really erase the ink. The ink has two phases, a color phase and a transparent phase. By heating or by friction (thus the name, I suppose) it changes to the transparent phase, by cooling to the color phase. Normally you change the phase by applying surface friction using a rubber, but you can also make it all transparent by storing at a hot place (I've heard the inside of a hot car is warm enough). And by cooling (in a freezer), you can re-show all erased (i.e. transparent) content again. No doubt this is very smart, but you should be aware of the limits.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can be removed but it is a delicate task requiring some experience...I first did this over 50 years ago.  You should be drawing on some heavy velum that can withstand the erasing.  You will need an erasing shield and electric eraser with the coarse dark grey eraser to gently sand a layer of paper off with the ink.  It's easy to erase a hole.  If you're going to do a lot of ink drafting you may want to look into mylar!   Goid luck drafting ....computers suck!

Answer (score -1):

Not tested yet, but try using fabric whitener such as Bayclin.

Comment: So, bleach?  Also, this isn't really the site for making unfounded suggestions.